# Wrong matching in replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add the suffix `.min` to my files that are not in `vendor` folder.

```
let str = '/js/index.js';
let str2 = '/vendor/socket-io/library.js';
let myregex = new RegExp('^([^/vendor]*.*[^min]{3}\\.)([a-z]{1,2}s)', 'g');
let myreplace = '$1min.$2';
console.log(str.replace(myregex, myreplace));
console.log(str2.replace(myregex, myreplace));
```

Logs out

```
/js/index.min.js
/vendor/socket-io/library.min.js
```

For some reason it matches the `library.js` even though I excluded `/vendor` on:

```
^([^/vendor]*.*  ...
```

When tested on https://regex101.com/ it all checks out, but javascript thinks otherwise.

This is the list of the needed matching:

```
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css --> DO NOT MATCH
/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css --> DO NOT MATCH
/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js --> DO NOT MATCH
/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js --> DO NOT MATCH
/vendor/socket-io/library.js --> DO NOT MATCH
/js/index.js --> MATCH
/css/style.css --> MATCH
/some/other/script.js --> MATCH
```

Why?

Comment: `[^/vendor]` is the **class** of all characters that are _not_ `/`, `v`, `e`, `n`, `d`, `o` or `r`.

Comment: You have not "excluded" `/vendor` as a *sequence of chars*. What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew edited the question

Comment: Is `/vendor` always at the start of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `vendor` folder is the top folder, you may use

```
^(?!\/vendor(?:\/|$))(?!.*\.min\.[^.]*$)(.*\.)
```

Replace with `$1min.`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP9FzV/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\/vendor(?:\/|$))` - there can't be `/vendor/` or `/vendor` followed with the end of string immediately to the left
- `(?!.*\.min\.[^.]*$)` - after any 0+ chars, as many as possible, there should be no `.min.` followed with any chars other than `.` up to the end of string
- `(.*\.)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last `.` and the `.` itself.

The replacement string `$1min.` inserts Group 1 value and adds `min.` after it.

JS demo:

```js
var ss = ["/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", "/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css", "/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", "/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", "/vendor/socket-io/library.js", "/js/index.min.js", "/js/index.js", "/css/style.css", "/some/other/script.js"];
var re = /^(?!\/vendor(?:\/|$))(?!.*\.min\.[^.]*$)(.*\.)/;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(re, "$1min."));
}
```

Comment: ok it's working but only with multiline `m`. Can this be done without `m` and only with `g`? I HAVE to use only `g`

Comment: @Moshe: You do not need any `m`. You get separate strings as input. My demo is a single line with line breaks inside, that is why I used `m` modifier. If your input is also a multiline string like the one in the demo, you can use `'gm'`, but I doubt it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the regex you are looking for.

```
^(((?!\/vendor)(?!\.min\.).)*?)(\..+)$
```

This regular expression works as follows:

1. Capture all characters (but as few as possible) that does not contain `vendor` or `.min.`
2. Capture `.` followed by any characters (but must have at least 1) *you can change the `.` to anything you'd like. I left it as `.` since extensions can include many characters*

Make your replacement text the following: `$1.min$3`.

---

**Input**

```
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css
/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
/vendor/socket-io/library.js
/js/index.js
/css/style.css
/some/other/script.js
```

**Output**

```
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css
/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
/vendor/socket-io/library.js
/js/index.min.js
/css/style.min.css
/some/other/script.min.js
```